# Как заменить input в python на виджеты

Tags: python, input, виджет

Делаю интерактивный нотебук в jupyter. Сначала общение с пользователем осуществлялось через inputы.
Решила сделать симпатичней и заменить input на кнопки и текстовые поля из ipywidgets. Проблема в том, что теперь программа не ждет ответа пользователя, пока он нажмет на кнопку или введет текст, а просто рисует кнопки и выполняет весь код сразу.

Как притормозить код, чтобы он не выполнялся пока пользователь не нажмет на кнопку?
Пока могу только завершить часть кода виджетом, а в функцию, задающую виджет пихнуть остальной код, но виджеты предполагаются в том числе внутри циклов, и тут все ломается, надо, что бы кнопка срабатывала именно как input.

Не могу приложить код, т.к. он огромный и со сложной конструкцией, извините(((

Help pls. Добра

Answer (score 2):

попробуйте использовать PyQT, там представлен обширный набор виджетов для ввода информации

Comment: Молодец! Поздравляю вас с первым ответом!